# Image not appearing in mobile view

Tags: javascript, css, image

I've been developing a mobile-first site, using Firefox as the primary browser.  I have a branding logo at the top of the page, loaded by way of the WordPress customizer.  The logo appears fine in Firefox, but disappears in Chrome and Safari when at a width of 320px.  (That's the base width for this project.)

I'm just troubleshooting and trying to find the best way to fix the problem.  I'm not really sure what's causing the issue, yet, though.  I was hoping to get some other perspectives on this.

Here's the link:
--- link removed ---

Thanks!

Comment: Well, you can start by showing us some code.

Comment: Thought I did.  I provided a link to the page.

Comment: Some observations, but not an answer, really. 1) There's a -185px left margin on the img, and the image becomes super small when the containing `a` gets smaller, so it ends up out of the window to the left. Firefox does not seem to respect this margin. 2) Disabling the `display: inline-block` on the containing `a` also has a different effect. Webkit calculates the image width from the containing `a` with it enabled, but Firefox does not change the image width based on the parent with it enabled.

Comment: Anyway, when debugging, use "inspect element" in the browser, and move the inspector to its own window, then just try resizing the window that has  the site, and try changing the css live in the inspector and see the effects.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you something that had helped me a lot of times when I did not know from where comes a problem:
 Reduce the content only to the part you want to fix(or in case if you have a bug and do not know from where comes - start removing code element by element).
BTW in the developer tools is showing a lot of errors.

Comment: Thanks, Marin.  That is good advice.  I will try that.  The errors are mostly being thrown by an extension and a video plugin.  It seems unrelated to the image issue.  I've tried deactivating both of those, and nothing really changed that much.  Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Hardly an answer to the question, rather a comment. Also, what errors are you seeing? I see 6 errors, all resource loading failures of  `cast_sender.js`.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly effect you would like to achieve, but In next section: `@media (max-width: 568px) {
   
   .jquery .main-navigation ul, .jquery .pics ul {
    display: none !important;
   }` you can try adding `.col-1-4{
width:100%;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Marin.  I appreciate your suggestions.  I think my server at work may be contributing to the issue.  For the time being, though, switching the width and height from % to em has at least resulted in the images being visible in chrome and safari.  I think I'll have to wait until I can test it outside my workplace to be sure, though.  Lol.  Thanks, again.